Emulate Outlook 365 feature to "Snooze" emails in the Outlook Desktop client
Outlook 365 (web client) contains a feature to "Snooze" emails, which effectively hides them until a specified time.
The Outlook desktop client does not contain this feature. (Microsoft has been promising for more than a year that they are "considering this". 1500+ votes to date.)
Sometimes I open the web client to snooze an email. I would like a simpler workaround that emulates this functionality.

I created an Outlook macro (VBA) that approximates this functionality. It forwards the email to myself and adds a 1-day "Delay Delivery", which effectively hides the email from my inbox for 24 hours. I added a link to the macro in my Quick Access Toolbar, so now it's even more conveniently accessible than the Web client!
Public Sub SnoozeMessage()
'This macro will send the selected email item back to me 1 day from now.
'(Snoozed message can be accessed in the Outbox folder in the meantime.)
'(Uses "Delayed Delivery" functionality.)

    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Item = GetCurrentItem()
    
    If Item Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No item selected.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        MsgBox "Snoozing this item for 1 day: " & Item.Subject
        With Item
            .To = "MyName@MyPlace.com"
            .Subject = Item.Subject + " [SNOOZED]" 'appends a tag to the subject line to keep track of how often I've snoozed it.
            .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("d", 1, Now)
            Debug.Print Item.DeferredDeliveryTime
            .Send
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Selected item is not an email.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
'Fetches the currently selected Outlook item
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case objApp.ActiveWindow.Class
        Case olInspector
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case olExplorer
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End Select
    
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function

To adjust the default delay period, consult the DateAdd documentation.
I thought about making the duration configurable at runtime, but that would require customizing the MsgBox, and I'm out of time, so that will just have to wait for another sprint.
